# Zeroes of a Complex polynomial with complex numbers as coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Solve the following completely,
$$F(x)=x^4-(13+7i)x^3-(11-195i/2)x^2+(143-15i/2)x+195i/2 = 0$$
Following the C.R.T I expanded the function came up with,

$$x^4-13x^3-11x^2+143x=0$$
Which later gave me
$(x^2-11)(x-13)=0$, thus,
$$x=0, x=13, x=\pm\sqrt{11}$$
I wanted to confirm with you since I have an alternative method of multiplying each complex coefficient with it's conjugate to eliminate
the"i"imaginary
Now my question is,
(1.) is what I did correct?
(2.) Is the alternative method correct and if yes, can I get the same answers?

Comment: What does C.R.T stand for?

Comment: Roots come in complex-conjugate pairs, so if $x=i\sqrt{11}$ is a root then $x=-i\sqrt{11}$ also has to be a root. Presumably $x=-\sqrt 11$ is a typo and should be $x=-i\sqrt 11$. But either way, your solutions are not correct, for example $F(0)=195I/2$, so $x=0$ can't be a root.

Comment: Roots only come in complex conjugate pairs if the coefficients of the polynomial are real numbers (or a common non-zero complex multiple of real numbers). The equation $\ x^4-13x^3-11x^2+143x=0\ $ apparently comes from ignoring the imaginary parts of the coefficients.  But the roots of that polynomial are not roots of the original polynomial, so I don't see how they can be of any assistance.

Comment: You can multiply the whole polynomial by its complex conjugate, and that will get you a polynomial with real coefficients – but with degree eight.

Comment: $$
x^8-26x^7+196x^6-793x^5+\frac{24057}{4}x^4-\frac{11947}{2}x^3+\frac{158071}{4}x^2-\frac{2925}{2}x+\frac{38025}{4}\ .
$$
According to WolframAlpha the greatest common divisor of this polynomial and its derivative [is $\ \frac{1}{4}\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialGCD%5B+x%5E8-26x%5E7%2B196x%5E6-793x%5E5%2B24057x%5E4%2F4-11947x%5E3%2F2%2B158071x%5E2%2F4-2925x%2F2%2B38025%2F4%2C+++8x%5E7-182x%5E6%2B1176x%5E5-3965x%5E4%2B24057x%5E3-35841x%5E2%2F2%2B158071x%2F2-2925%2F2%5D).

Comment: The original polynomial therefore has no real roots, because any such would have to have been a multiple root of this polynomial, which would then have to share a divisor of positive degree with its derivative.